# Need help to trigger dialogue using counter text as condition in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Ok so I am making a game, 2D, in which the player can proceed through the level only if he has 3 coins. One way to do that was trigger a dialogue change if the coin counter that I made had "X 3" written on it (there are only 3 coins through the level). Even though i gave it the condition, the next dialogue won't appear , nor does the first one get destroyed. Im using .png images for dialogue bubbles so theyre separate gameObjects.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject DialogueOld;
    public SpriteRenderer DialogueNew;
    public Text counter;

    void Start()
    {
        counter = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("player") && (counter.text == ("X " + "3")) )
        {
            Destroy(DialogueOld.gameObject);
            DialogueNew.enabled = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Once the player enters the collider of the npc (on which the script goes), the previous dialogue should be destroyed and the next should be enabled, however it just doesnt work and it keeps on showing the old dialogue, I'm guessing theres something wrong with the if statement?

Comment: Does this DialogueDestroyer object has a collider on it?

Comment: yeah i attached it to the npc, which has a trigger object collider on it

Comment: try using OnCollisionEnter2D instead of OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: First check if you are detecting the collision at all. Add `Debug.Log("Collision");` before the if statement. If you are not getting the log, you propably doing something wrong with colliders or tagging.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `DialogueOld.enabled = false;`